# How to Open a different link on a page with python selenium for scraping?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

[image]I have the below code for opening the "New" link of a page which has the data i want to **scrape** (As in the screenshot). It's working ok and actually clicking the link but the soup i get is still for content under "Popular" (As in screenshot).

What am i doing wrong?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.homeworkmarket.com/fields/business-finance")
time.sleep(2)
doc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a')[0]
doc.click()
time.sleep(10)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

The rest of the code for **scraping** href links:

```
question_links = soup.find_all(class_='css-e5w42e')
final_links = []
for link in question_links:
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        link = 'https://www.homeworkmarket.com' + str(link.attrs['href'])
        print(link)
        final_links.append(link)
```

Comment: what data you want to scrape ? also use @ to reply

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey, thanks. I want to scrap the href links under the "New" section. My current code is doing it but only for the "Popular" section despite using find_elements_by_xpath to find and click the "New" section. will appreciate any help

Comment: okay check out the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to click on New, cause elements are already present in HTML DOM:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.homeworkmarket.com/fields/business-finance")

for link in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(*//a[text()='New']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'css')])[3]/following-sibling::div/section/descendant::a[contains(@class,'css')]"):
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Initial 80 links are from popular tab and rest should be from new tab.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't open a new page, just expands some area on existing page.
The page source contains this data even before expanding it visually, this is why clicking that button still gives you the same `page` data by performing

```
page = driver.page_source
```

Comment: how then should i go about it?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: i want to scrap for links under the "New" section". The current code i have is successfully getting me the ones under the "Popular" section. I have added the entire code snippet.

Comment: I try to use find_elements_by_xpath to find and click the "New" section which works but the content scrapped is still under popular